# css3 transition display property problelm workaround needed

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I'm building a **mobile app**. You can slide through **multiple elements**. I've tried the `jquery` **animate** function but I wasn't satisfied... So I took a dive into `css3` transitions. And that is where I'm stuck. The application's **navigation** module depends on the display property of the slided elements using `jquery`'s is("visible"). Would like to leave it that way.

The problem is that **webkit** isn't able to use a transaction after the **display property** is changed. Adding a transition css class after display the property change doesn't help either. And that is what I don't understand. Somehow webkit knows I've changed the display property before. Why?

All workarounds are based on not using the display property.*Might be there a workaround by changing the element in a way the browser doesn't know the element was changed from none to show??* A few years have passed...

So I would like to know if there is an another workaround so I'm able to use the display property or any other solution or am I really forced to don't use the display property? In that case I have to check the current position of the outer elements and determine which navigation options should be available.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle that shows what exactly is not working?
Currently, I assume you mean something like this:
el.style.display = ""; el.className = "prettycooltransition"

Comment: Haven't found an usable workaround myself yet. So finally I've chosen to determine if an element is in the viewport or not using http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Comment: Hm, ok, still an interesting problem. Maybe I will still try to find a workaround for this, just because I´m curious :D

Comment: Maybe cloning an element before the display property might help. For example. if the application is initializing, the elements are cloned and placed outside of the viewport. the original element can be hidden, when made visible we clone the clone and replace it for the original element. sounds like we have then an untouched display property and valid state to execute a successful transition.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MvH_MontySCOUT/AALmx/3/ If you open this in chrome it shows the original problem. I'd like to find a workaround to be able to still use the display property :D This evening i'll try the above possible workaround.

Comment: Playing around with this a bit, I figured out the problem: Chrome (and FF, too) do not like to animate elements which have a display: none-property in any external CSS selector, whereas directly adding style="display: none" to the external element creates the desired effect. Searching for a good workaround to use this...

Comment: Dont ask me why, but with a window.setTimeout(fn, 0) for the new position of #a3 it works in Chrome (but not in FF), but with some delay...

Comment: I assume that the browser caches the display property before each repaint of the page and does not animate the elements with the display: none-property set. Within the next repaint, it now notices the changed display and displays the element, but with no animation.
With the direct setting and removing of the display property, you seem to cause an immediate repaint, and the timeout gives us enought time for the browser to have the element displayed before it is animated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I mentioned in the comments above, my suggested solution would be this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/AALmx/5/
You first show the hidden elements, then with a minimal delay of 20 you kickoff the animations.

```
$hiddenElement.show()
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $hiddenElement.css("right", "0")
    $toBeHiddenElement.css("left", "-50%")
    // and so on
})
```

Your users probably wont notice that, and the delay is ways shorter than your animation, so there is no problem with the usability of your page.